# ToolTip in Text inside RichTextBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm working with code editor and I just wanted to add tooltip for everytext that Ill inputed in richtextbox (served as code-editor) .

Till I see this guide right here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464085/WinForms-RichTextBox-ToolTip-like-Visual-Studios

It's the same thing that I want to find though the time I download it there's a file missing specifically its mainform .

So I just want to ask if how to do it without using any .dll file.

Sample: I type "abc" in rtb then when I mouse hover it a tooltip with text: this is an alphabet will appear. Same as with "123" a when I mousehover tooltip with text: this is a number will appear.

Comment: you want in your RTB, When I type "C# is Awesome" you need to get Awesome only in Tooltip or Full Sentence

Comment: different text as i inputed in rtb could be if possible . if i inputted "C# is Awesome" tooltip with message "its really Awesome" will appear .something like that ... just like what in the link shows but its ok in me if its just a simple tooltip and dont have border ...

Comment: "Its really" is Commmon words has to attach with Last Word you typed in RTB. Please tell me the sample Input and output

Comment: inputtext in rtb-> abc = outputtext (when text get mouseover)-> this is an alphabet . and if its 123 -> inputtext (when text get mouseover)-> this is a number .

Comment: Please check the Answer , Please let me know Is this waht you are expecting?

Comment: @AkshayJoy maam rtbTypedText does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this Sample, One way to Achieve

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string rtbTypedText = "";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }





        private void richTextBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


           // MessageBox.Show(text);

        }

        private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar))
            {
                int result = 0;
                string s = richTextBox1.Text;

                string text = "";
                string[] sp = s.Split(' ');

                if (sp.Length == 0)
                    rtbTypedText = s;
                else
                    rtbTypedText = sp[sp.Length - 1];


                bool typeStatus = int.TryParse(rtbTypedText, out result);
                if (typeStatus == true)
                    toolTip1.Show("It is a Number", richTextBox1);
                else
                    toolTip1.Show("It is an Alphabet", richTextBox1);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Akyshay Joy rtbTypedText does not exist maam

Comment: Please declare strign varible on global area

Comment: i also add ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip(); it already runs but it has no change... :(

Comment: Please Drag and Drop the Tooltip component form Toolbox. It works fine in my code.

Comment: what should i type in rt? to achieve the tooltip?

Comment: Please type some text and Integer values each time check the MouseHOve, you can see the Tooltip

Comment: same thing as i type numbers (123123) but when i mouseover it it doesnt appear :(

Comment: and string text = ""; never used

Comment: You can sutomize the code for null String. I just gave the code for ur need

Comment: How can its possible for different behavior. Its working in my System, what is the issue , Please Debug ur code

Comment: i retry it and i add toolTip1 from toolbar but still it doenst work . can you pls repost your code used in your screenshot sir? thanks

Comment: heres the ss sir: http://oi45.tinypic.com/33wv3ox.jpg i mouseover it but it doesnt work .code used are all include above .and tooltip1 added same with richtextbox1

Comment: I got ur Problem , You used RichTextBox as Dock In Parent Container right.? so when ever you type something, We wrote the event in MouseHover, So Cusrsor has to move Out the RicHTextBox, then only it will work, Event has to fire only when MouseHover happened

Comment: use Unlock in Parent Container, and when ever you type something move the cusror out of RichTextBox and then only only MouseHover event will occur

Comment: even i dont fill it (dock) still i dont get the tooltip sir :/ ... i tried it many times already but i dont get the same result as yours :/

Comment: Wait I think you want the Tooltip when ever you press space for each space you need whether the text is number or Alphabet.? I will modify and put it again

Comment: still no tooltip showed -_- ... can you upload your work in fileuploader sir?^^ if you dont mind and if its ok hehe ... im using c#2010 express btw ... i copy all no errors but still no tooltip showed the time i mousehover the text .

Comment: Can u Please put Breakpoint in Keypress event. and try to see the it. Its working in my system. It can't show different behaviour

Comment: Dude Please sent your Sample Project to akshayjoyinfo@gmail.com

Comment: sir just send me project in through sendspace.com .big thanks sir!

Comment: sir it worked the time i press space .but when i try to do it 12312312 the nextline it mulfunction and says this is an alphabet which is not .though if i use space between group of nums it will change to this is a number ... but sir can i be mousehover if its ok? w/o using keypress(space or anything?) i mean if cursor was above text then automatically the tooltip will shows and identify wgat type is it? if not sir i really understand ... really bigthanks and sorry for inconvenience ...

Comment: Am using only space , you can add the Logic for New Line also... seperately.

Comment: if you get solution please make as an Answer