# Displaying ToolTip to MouseHover Text

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, mousehover

Related to this question:
[Displaying tooltip on mouse hover of a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873175/displaying-tooltip-on-mouse-hover-of-a-text)

How can I do the same thing on a keyword in the RichTextBox but not a link?

In RichTextBox I type:

```
Hello World, How are You?
```

I set hovering the word "World" for tooltip and when it hovers ToolTip will appear saying "this is world"!

But if it hovers out of the RichTextBox or in the word "World" itself, tooltip will disappear.

Comment: Did you like PlaceHolder ?

Comment: i didnt even know that @RameshRajendran whats that? sorry newbie here

Comment: Look this samples :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008303/tooltip-in-text-inside-richtextbox

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142890/tooltip-in-specifictext-inside-richtextbox-using-mouseover

Comment: @RameshRajendran thats my threads long time ago but it doesnt work properly, regarding with issues of hovering /displaying and disposing tooltip

Comment: @Elegiac just show the tooltip on hovering a word or even a phrase (containing some words)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little simple. You have to use the `GetCharIndexFromPosition` method of your `RichTextBox` to get the `Char index` under the `Mouse Pointer`, make some simple loops to find the whole word and then show it in a `Tooltip popup` normally. Here is the code:

```
    string punctuations = " ,.;!?'\")]}\n";
    //This saves your words with their corresponding definitions/details
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    ToolTip tt = new ToolTip();
    int k;
    int lineBreakIndex = 60;
    int textHeight;
    //MouseMove event handler for your richTextBox1
    private void richTextBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
        if (richTextBox1.TextLength == 0) return;
        Point lastCharPoint = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.TextLength - 1);
        if (e.Y > textHeight ||  (e.Y  >= lastCharPoint.Y && e.X > lastCharPoint.X + textHeight - lastCharPoint.Y))            
        {
            tt.Hide(richTextBox1);
            k = -1;
            return;
        } 
        int i = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location);            
        int m = i, n = i;
        while (m>-1&&!punctuations.Contains(richTextBox1.Text[m])) m--;            
        m++;
        while (n<richTextBox1.TextLength&&!punctuations.Contains(richTextBox1.Text[n])) n++;
        if (n > m){
            string word = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(m, n - m);
            if (dict.ContainsKey(word)){
                if (k != m){
                    tt.ToolTipTitle = word;
                    tt.Show(dict[word], richTextBox1, e.X, e.Y + 10);
                    k = m;
                }
            }
            else{
                tt.Hide(richTextBox1);
                k = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    //This will get the entry text with lines broken.
    private string GetEntryText(string key){
        string s = dict[key];
        int lastLineEnd = lineBreakIndex;
        for (int i = lastLineEnd; i < s.Length; i += lineBreakIndex)
        {
            while (s[i] != ' '){
                if (--i < 0) break;                    
            }
            i++;
            s = s.Insert(i, "\n");
            lastLineEnd = i+1;
        }
        return s;
    }
    //MouseLeave event handler for your richTextBox1
    private void richTextBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e){
        tt.Hide(richTextBox1);
        k = -1;
    }
    //ContentsResized event handler for your richTextBox1
    private void richTextBox1_ContentsResized(object sender, ContentsResizedEventArgs e)
    {
        textHeight = e.NewRectangle.Height;
    }
    //Here are some sample words with definitions:
    dict.Add("world", "- World is a common name for the whole of human civilization, specifically human experience, history, or the human condition in general, worldwide, i.e. anywhere on Earth.");
    dict.Add("geek", "- A person who is single-minded or accomplished in scientific or technical pursuits but is felt to be socially inept");
```

[image]

Comment: sir i copy those script but doesnt work in mine dunno whats the prob

Comment: @Elegiac do you know how to register `event handlers` in c#?

Comment: aswesome sir! it worked sir. .. but only in 1st word world . how about in others? same as geek

Comment: @Elegiac your RichTextBox should contain such words, then you just hover the mouse on the keywords. These keywords should be added to the `Dictionary` **dict** in my code (together with their meaning/details/definition).

Comment: i dunno why but when i type random words with geeks/ world on it some are ok but some places doesnt work geeks and world

Comment: @Elegiac if there are two (or more) words `world` positioning next to each other (continuously) such as `world world world` then the ToolTip will popup only 1 time for the first `world` you hover on (that's by design).

Comment: how about in here sir? 
asdasdasssd geek          



asdasdsd world


                                           GEEK geek







      world

Comment: can we do it worked all world and not 1st pls?:) if its ok ill accept it if it does really need it so bad

Comment: @Elegiac doesn't it work for you? I've tried with that text and it also worked.

Comment: sometimes it only work for 1st geek and 1st world to hover :/

Comment: @Elegiac OK, it won't work in that case (as shown in your picture). I updated the code and tested, it works now.

Comment: ill just try to ask it on separate question . ill accept this answer since it worked even it still have a bug ... bigthanks sir! :)